React native permission warning upload loading: No permission handler detected
I have a react native project. Within this react native project, I want to get a users location if they give permission so that I can get their longitude and latitude. I was not getting an issue when I first implemented it but I am getting an error / warning all of the sudden about permissions and I am not sure where this error is coming from.
Here is the screen that I am seeing:

I have made several changes to my project but none of it is being effective.
Here is my podfile:
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '15.0'
prepare_react_native_project!

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

target 'Grubber' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Removing Flipper completely
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,  # Remove this line
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # Add the required permissions pods with modular headers
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  
  # Add Firebase pods
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'GrubberTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0'
      end
    end
  end
end

Here is my info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Grubber</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>mailto</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need your location to show nearby restaurants.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need your location to show nearby restaurants.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your photos are used to allow you to select images to attach to your posts.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>

If anyone knows how to help me fix this issue, I would be very grateful.
Every time I build the project in xcode I run the following command in terminal:
cd ios
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
pod install 
cd ..
npx react-native run-ios --device "AbuVibes iPhone"   

